# multi array form won't store variables

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have a form that submits to update.php which should take the POST variables and store them in another file

the form:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Proficiencies:</legend>
        <span>Name:</span> <span>exp:</span> <span>Rank:</span><br/>
        <?php
             $x = 0;
             if ($proficiencies) {
                foreach ($proficiencies as $proficiency) {
                        echo '<input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'name\']" value="'.$proficiency["name"].'"/>';
                        echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'exp\']" value="'.$proficiency["exp"].'"/>';
                        echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'rank\']" value="'.$proficiency["rank"].'"/>';
                        echo '<br/>';
                        $x++;
               }
            }
           echo '<input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'name\']"/>';
           echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'exp\']"/>';
           echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'rank\']"/>';
       ?>

</fieldset>
```

update.php:

```
<?php
echo 'making changes';
$user = fopen('sheets/'.$_COOKIE['username'].'.php', 'w+');
fwrite ($user, '<?php
$proficiencies = array(
');
foreach ($_POST['proficiencies'] as $proficiency) {
    if ($proficiency["name"]) {
        fwrite ($user, '    array(
        "name" => "'.$proficiency["name"].'",
        "exp" => "'.$proficiency["exp"].'",
        "rank" => "'.$proficiency["rank"].'",
    ),
'
        );
    }
}
fwrite ($user, ');
?>');
fclose($user);
?>
```

I have tried many different ways of doing this but it just won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html form names you are not allowed to use quotes

change

```
echo '<input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'name\']" value="'.$proficiency["name"].'"/>';
echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'exp\']" value="'.$proficiency["exp"].'"/>';
echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][\'rank\']" value="'.$proficiency["rank"].'"/>';
```

To:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][name]" value="'.$proficiency["name"].'"/>';
echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][exp]" value="'.$proficiency["exp"].'"/>';
echo ' <input type="text" name="proficiencies['.$x.'][rank]" value="'.$proficiency["rank"].'"/>';
```

it should be fine

Comment: **Correction:** you can use quotes in form name, but it will carried as if its the name so in the $_POST['proficiencies'] there should be keys like $proficiency["'name'"] - notice the single quotes inside the double ones :P